# MATLAB Workspace gives me different values

Tags: matlab

What do the spreadsheets in a MATLAB workspace represent? I say this because extracting the data from a figure and the workspace from the original plot yield different data values.

Comment: Could you include code? And be more specific as to what the differences in the data are? It is hard to understand your problem without more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spreadsheets are the current values.  If they're different from your plots there's a few possible answers.

1. You're mistaken, comparing different variables than you think you are, transposing, etc.
2. You've done something to change the values since they were plotted
3. They were plotted inside a function without the changes being passed back out to the workspace
4. An actual glitch (i think this all the time until i realize my mistake)